# Im trying to put a thumbnail in my ruby on rails project, How would I save the image in mysql?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, thumbnails

This is my code below in the ruby on rails project. As for mysql, How would I save an image in the database so when the application calls "user.image" it knows what to call? is it just a link to the image that goes in the "image" column? is it url? and must the picture be saved anywhere else for it to display properly?

```
 <div class="page-header">
      <h2>Users</h2>
    </div>

    <% @users.each do |user| %>

    <div class="user">
      <ul class="thumbnails">
      <li class="span2">
        <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
          <img src="<%= user.image %>" alt="<%= user.nickname %>">
        </a>
      </li>

      <strong><%= user.nickname%></strong>
      <p><%= user.first_name%> <%= user.last_name%></p>
        <div class="meta">
          <%= link_to 'Show', user %>
        </div>
    </div>

    </ul>
    <% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried looking at Carrierwave Gem?

Here is the rails cast.

http://railscasts.com/episodes/253-carrierwave-file-uploads

I am new to rails as well and found this a great way to upload images for just what you are trying to do.

Here is the github page

https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave

Comment: Did you try this? Do you need more help.

Comment: the rails migrate command, will it work if I have the project set up with a mysql database?

Comment: I do not understand? Yes migration will work with MySQL, but I do not think that is the question. If you want to have an image stored try this gem it works well and is super easy! Please give me the check and an upvote if it works...